# Implementation of collide method by creating a rectangle that is smaller than the object

Tags: python, sprite, pygame, collision, rect

How would I create a rectangle that is smaller than the image? As far as I know, the only way to create a rect around the image is by using:

```
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

But that creates a rect that is larger than the image. Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Create a new sprite with a rect smaller than the one of another sprite? Make the collision detection use a smaller sprite? Give some more detail and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "Rectangle" in a Pygame is a simple object to pass coordinates on surfaces between functions and methods. There is the `pygame.rect.Rect` class, to which you pass (x, y, width, height)  to instantiate. Aside from that specific class, almost all functions in pygame that require a rectangle, will also accept an ordinary tuple of (x,y, width, height) - including collision verifications.